# Pandas - Label x-axis of time series plot with column names

Tags: python, pandas, plot, header, time-series

I have a dataframe that has dates as indexes and time in the header. The dates have been selected are for summer months of Australia and formatted to datetime. The time range is for a 24-hour period at 30-minute resolution. I've left time untouched as a string type.

The first five rows are shown in the link below:

[first 5 rows of dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CpyS58mAcOKaraJyOgWJQm5SGkpcYesr/view?usp=sharing)

The problem I have is when plotting the dataframe. I can't seem to have the x-axis labelled with the names of each column -> in my case, the 30-minute interval times for a 24-hour period (view in the link below). The figure is only plotted with time labels inserted at 0:30, 5:30, 10:30, 15:30 and 20:30.

[time-series plot 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N39Nopv2n5o_ZWRLQw0us1Q3IcVbkfJm/view?usp=sharing)

If I add tick marks, the plot squeezes the printed labels on the axis towards the left and adds tick marks after them but not in between these labels. View in the link below.

[time-series plot 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zarwK3feXk-YvUz9HkazwOe7xspus-8M/view?usp=sharing)

I'm wondering if this is because I have not converted time into datetime format or because of some other cause. Would greatly appreciate some insight in this and some get some help in how to properly label the x-axis with all the column names.

Comment: Hi. Whenever possible, please copy/paste code and data examples into the post. This makes it easier for answers to use the example provided to test and show the proposed solution

Answer (score 0):

Since Pandas uses matplotlib for plotting, this is mostly a matplotlib question.

The default in matplotlib is to only have tick labels on the major ticks. So if you specify that all ticks are major ticks, you hopefully get what you want:

```
from matplotlib import ticker
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```